# what's wrong with fb like button?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

here is my situation:
[image]

i dont know why it return automatically, this error just happened with few details page, others are good`

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=209985355712105&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com{0}&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=90&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=arial&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:90px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

value {0} can be change depend on page url detail. for example when user clicked view detail and then the url will be: example.com/viewdetail/item1.
then the value {0} will be change to: /viewdetail/item1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This also happens, when you're trying to like `localhost` or anything else that is unreachable for Facebook (HTTP 404 or 403).
You should check if the given `href` is existent from the outer web and for the Facebook agent.

Also check if the Linter (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) can reach your webpage.

Comment: execuse me! i border you again, i have a question: as i told above, the value {0} will be change to /viewdetail/item1 but follow FB enscrypt i change it to '%2Fviewdetail%2Fitem1' then i pressed like, it back to error above, so i copied the url 'example.com%2Fviewdetail%2Fitem1' and checked them at  (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) then i pressed like again, and this time it works, so can you tell me why?

Comment: @Son I had an error, that the og:tags were only used when I used the Linter first, but the error you described never happened to me. Sorry, I can't help you with that. :(